# Why the index out of bounds error in this arraylist?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexing

Why does this code cause an index out of bounds error?

```
ArrayList<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++){
    list2.add(i); //adding numbers to arraylist.  Length is equal to 10
}
int size = list2.size(); //size now equals 10

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    if (list2.get(i) == 3 || list2.get(i) == 4)
    list2.remove(i);
System.out.println(list2);
```

Comment: You remove items from the arraylist but never update the `size` variable. So after the first `remove`, `size` is too large.

Answer (score 1):

The first size is `10`, but when you remove an element, it becomes 9, so when the index `i` gets to `9` you can't access the box 9 has it does not exists (as index starts at `0`)

---

You need to get the current size at each iteration as you're modifying it

```
for (int i = 0; i < list2.size(); i++) {
    if (list2.get(i) == 3 || list2.get(i) == 4) {
        list2.remove(i);
    }
}
//[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Also the `4` is not deleted, why ?

- Because when you check index `2` you find the value `3` so you remove it,
- then all the values go down in the list, the value `4` is not at index `2`,
- as `i` will be now `3` you won't check that box

---

To remove both `3` and `4` you can use one of the following solution:

- `list2.removeIf(i -> i == 3 || i == 4);`
- `list2 = list2.stream()
                .filter(i -> i != 3 && i != 4)
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));`